# iPhone application doesn't install from anywhere else other than the dev machine

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, installation, itunes

I created an iPhone application. I am distributing it with the ad hoc method. It installs just fine from the iTunes installed on the machine where the app was created. Anywhere else the iTunes just gives the error 'Resources have been modified'.

Please help.

Comment: Did you add the correct provisioning profile on the other machine? If you're installing on a different device, then that device's UUID has to be added to the profile on iTunes Connect.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Yes i did :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible it *is* being changed. You should distribute your app as an .ipa file, this will shield it from changes.

Create a folder called Payload and place your .app folder inside of it. Zip up the Payload folder using normal compression, then rename the file with a .ipa extension.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to tewha's answer:

One thing to note is that if you want the app's artwork to appear in iTunes (rather than a generic app icon), you need to place a file called iTunesArtwork (with no extension) into the zip file on the same level as the Payload folder (not in it). This is actually a jpeg file of a 512x512 image and this will appear in iTunes for the app. When I was converting folders, I didn't have the original images so I just left them off, the app works fine you just get the generic icon.